# java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306

Tags: maven, jdbc, mariadb

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/SearchEngineApp
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:708)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:230)
    at com.Accio.DatabaseConnection.getConnection(DatabaseConnection.java:21)
    at com.Accio.DatabaseConnection.getConnection(DatabaseConnection.java:16)
    at com.Accio.Search.doGet(Search.java:18)
```

I'm facing some issues with Jdbc:mariadb connection. I have already installed the JDBC Driver on Pom.xml via Maven, but I am still facing issues.

The DatabaseConnection code:

```java
package com.Accio;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class DatabaseConnection {

    static Connection connection = null;

    public static Connection getConnection(){
        if(connection!=null) return connection;

        String user = "root";
        String pwd = "";
        String db = "SearchEngineApp";

        return getConnection(user,pwd,db);
    }

    private static Connection getConnection(String user , String password , String database){
        try {
            String url = "jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/"+database;
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,password);
        }catch(SQLException sqlException){
            sqlException.printStackTrace();
        }
        return connection;
    }
}
```

The Search code:

```java
package com.Accio;

import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.util.*;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

@WebServlet("/Search")
public class Search extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doGet (HttpServletRequest request , HttpServletResponse response)throws IOException{
        String keyword = request.getParameter("keyword");
        Connection connection = DatabaseConnection.getConnection();
        try {
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("Insert into history values(?, ?);");
            preparedStatement.setString(1,keyword);
            preparedStatement.setString(2,"http://localhost:8080/SearchEngine/Search?keyword="+keyword);
            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

            ResultSet resultSet = connection.createStatement().executeQuery("select pagetitle, pagelink, (length(lower(pageText))-length(replace(lower(pageText),'"+keyword.toLowerCase()+"','')))/length('"+keyword.toLowerCase()+"') as countoccurence from pages order by countoccurence desc limit 30");
            ArrayList<SearchResult> results = new ArrayList<>();

            while (resultSet.next()){
                SearchResult searchResult = new SearchResult();
                searchResult.setTitle(resultSet.getString("pageTitle"));
                searchResult.setLink(resultSet.getString("pageLink"));
                results.add(searchResult);
            }

            for(SearchResult result : results){
                System.out.println(result.getTitle()+"\n"+result.getLink()+"\n");
            }
            request.setAttribute("results" , results);
            request.getRequestDispatcher("search.jsp").forward(request,response);
            response.setContentType("text/html");
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        }catch(SQLException | ServletException sqlException){
            sqlException.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>SearchEngine</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>20</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>20</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>SearchEngine Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
      <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
      <version>LATEST</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>SearchEngine</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

I can't for the life of me figure out what the issue is here. Another thing is, I am using the same DatabaseConnection code for another part of the question, but it seems to work fine there but not here for some reason.

Comment: You need to add `Class.forName("org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver")` (e.g. in a static initializer of `DatabaseConnection`) to load the driver if the driver is in `WEB-INF/lib` of your WAR instead of on the initial classpath of Tomcat itself (automatic driver loading doesn't work in this case, because it was triggered with only the initial classpath, not your WAR classpath). That said, you generally should not use `DriverManager`, but instead use a configured `javax.sql.DataSource` implementation backed by a connection pool.

Comment: Also, your current use of `DatabaseConnection` will blow up in your face if your web application handles more than one request concurrently, as you'll be sharing the same connection with multiple threads, which will lead to undefined behaviour.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel The `Class.forName()` line hasn't been needed since 2006, and it would have failed in exactly the same way. The problem here is the missing JAR file, not the code.

Comment: @user207421 I have replied to your claims about this a dozen or so times in the past few years, and it is simply not true. Yes, in simple applications with one classpath, you don't need `Class.forName`, but in more complex applications, like web applications with a composite classpath, and/or where `DriverManager` was already used before, it may not have loaded all drivers, and given automatic driver loading runs only **once**, drivers added later, or in a different branch of the classloader hierarchy will need to be loaded explicitly to be accessible.

Comment: @user207421 And that is exactly the case with web applications. For example, Tomcat itself uses `DriverManager` while it starts, so automatic driver loading will only register drivers that are in the `lib` directory of Tomcat itself. Drivers which are in `WEB-INF/lib` of a WAR or exploded WAR will not have been registered and will need to be loaded explicitly, because once automatic driver loading has been triggered, it will not run again.

Comment: @user207421 And given the OP shows the pom.xml, and it has packaging set to war, we can assume that the driver *is* in `WEB-INF/lib`, and thus is on the classpath of the web application.